# how to access authorized user a custom tag helper

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to verify if the current authorized is in a specific role, using a custom tag helper. I want to use `UserManager.IsInRoleAsync()`, but I need to pass in a `User` object.

How can I access the current authorized user?

```
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    base.PreProcess(context, output);

    bool isInRole = _um.IsInRoleAsync(????, this.Roles); ;

    var policy = await AuthorizationPolicy.CombineAsync(_policy, new[] { this });
    var authResult = await _eva.AuthenticateAsync(policy, _http.HttpContext);
    var authorizeResult = await _eva.AuthorizeAsync(policy, authResult, _http.HttpContext, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rewriting some of the logic::

```
var foo = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser();

    if (!this.Roles.IsNull())
    {
        foo.RequireRole(this.Roles.Split(","));
    }

    if (!this.AuthenticationSchemes.IsNull())
    {
        foo.AddAuthenticationSchemes(this.AuthenticationSchemes);
    }

    var policy = foo.Build();
    var authResult = await _eva.AuthenticateAsync(policy, _http.HttpContext);
    var authorizeResult = await _eva.AuthorizeAsync(policy, authResult, _http.HttpContext, null);

    if (!authorizeResult.Succeeded)
    {
        output.SuppressOutput();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Combine [`ViewContextAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.viewcontextattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2), [`HttpContext.User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.user?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [`UserManager.GetUserAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getuserasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

```
[ViewContext]
public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    // ...

    var claimsPrincipal = ViewContext.HttpContext.User;
    var identityUser = await _um.GetUserAsync(claimsPrincipal);

    if (identityUser == null)
    {
        // Either no user is signed in or there's no match for the user in Identity.
        // ...
    }

    bool isInRole = _um.IsInRoleAsync(identityUser, this.Roles);

    // ...
}
```

Here's a breakdown of what's happening:

1. Using a property decorated with `[ViewContext]`, we can access the [`ViewContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.viewcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and its `HttpContext` property.
2. Given a `HttpContext`, we can access its `User` property and pass that into a call to `UserManager.GetUserAsync`, which returns the `IdentityUser` (or custom type) used by the Identity implementation.
3. We pass this `identityUser` value into `UserManager.IsInRoleAsync`.